# Laravel get joined data according to condition for joined table column

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi guys i am using laravel5.5
I have two tables Users and Services

> Users Table

1. id
2. name
3. email
4. password
5. address
6. city
7. country
8. zipcode

> Service table

1. id
2. User_id
3. name
4. description
5. price

> In User Model

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
}
```

> In Service Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Now in controller I need all services where user->zipcode = 20006
How can i get it
I have tried this below code

```
$services = Service::with('user')->where('user->zipcode', '20006')->get();
```

But it did not work.

thanks in advance.
Warm Regards:
Abdullah Shahid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it

```
$services = Service::whereHas('user', function($q)use($zipcode) {
                $q->where('zipcode' , $zipcode);
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$services = Service::with(['user'])->whereHas('user', function($q) {
                 $q->where('zipcode', '20006');
            })->get();
```

Comment: It return all services but only 2 matching users.
But I need both table with matching record same length.

Comment: I mean it will give us left join i need inner join so the both tables get the same no of records. Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks for the help but there is little bit changes.